# Whenever I connect my new laptop to the internet it slows everything

Tags: laptop, internet-connection, asus-laptop

I just got a new laptop about 3 days ago and since i got it, it always had a problem, that whenever I connect the new laptop to the internet it slows down the internet and prevent any other device from accessing the internet properly.
I've tried every solution on the internet but i just doesn't work, if it matters the internet connects usually to 2 phones, 1 tablet, the new laptop(which is the problem here), and a ps4.
Before getting that new laptop everything was going just fine, and also when I disconnect the laptop from the internet, the internet works fine with the other devices.
Please help it's really annoying since i got that laptop for college work and gaming.

Any answers are appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Have,you checked to see if it's download Windows updates when you connect to the internet? That would be my first guess

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting your laptop using an Ethernet cable to see if other devices get their network traffic congested as well this way.
If they don't then that's a good sign that your laptop is downloading something (like windows updates) and that is what is consuming your bandwidth. You could also try connecting the laptop to your network using the 5GHz frequency (dependant on your wireless adapter being capable of finding them and your modem being able to stream them) since this network is less used and often has a better bandwidth to work with. 
I would still highly recommend using data cable to download updates since it will be quite faster and you won't clog your wireless network.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience when a device connected to a network causes a massive slowdown on that network, it's usually the upload bandwidth that's being consumed.

Have you installed anything like DropBox, OneDrive, or similar which might be attempting to sync a lot of data from your system to 'The Cloud'?
If so, pause the application and see if your connectivity returns to normal.

Since it's an ASUS laptop, I presume it's running Windows 10.  If so, you can use the Task Manager's 'Processes' tab to view which applications are using the network.  Sort it by the Network Column and check the application that's consuming the bandwidth.

Comment: Well , the application is called "svchost.exe".                                   What is that? And why is it consuming so much internet?

Comment: It could be any number of services installed on your computer.  Most likely Windows Update, but we'll check that by: Open Task Manager and go to the Performance Tab.  At the bottom, click 'Open Resource Monitor'.  When Resource Monitor opens up, click on the Network Tab and have a look at the 'Network Activity' section.  Sort by 'Total (B/sec)' descending so that the largest consumer is at the top and then look at the address column.  This might give you an idea of what domain your computer is talking to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any information to go on, I'll go out on a limb and say your new machine could be downloading Windows updates, and your home network probably has a bufferbloat problem, so TCP congestion control isn't working, so your big downloads ruin things for everyone instead of sharing nicely. Fix your network's bufferbloat problem to fix this long-term. Short term, put your laptop on a fast network until it finishes downloading the updates it needs.

Comment: If someone wanted to fix their network's bufferbloat problem, as you advise, how would they go about doing that?  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Install OpenWrt or DD-WRT on your router, enable FQ-CoDel, and set up traffic shaping to make your router an ever-so-slight bottleneck on your network, so its anti-bufferbloat protection can kick in before bloated buffer queues build up on other network middleboxes. Or buy an EvenRoute.com IQrouter if you want a turn-key solution (I haven't used one, so can't vouch for it, but it seems to do exactly as I've suggested; even auto-tunes its traffic shaping for different times of day.